# How to .update m2m field in django

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many

I have:

```
class MyUser(Model):
    today_ref_viewed_ips = ManyToManyField(
        UniqAddress, 
        related_name='today_viewed_users', 
        verbose_name="Adresses visited referal link today")
    ...
```

On some croned daily request I do:

```
for u in MyUser.objects.all():
    u.today_ref_viewed_ips.clear()
```

Can it be done on DB server with update?

```
MyUser.objects.all().update(...)
```

---

Ok, I can't update, thanks. But only thing I need is to TRUNCATE m2m internal table, is it possible to perform from django? How to know it's name whithout  mysql's console "SHOW TABLES"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Query-1:**

**No, you cannot use [`.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) method to update a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).**

Django's `.update()` method does not support ManyToManyField.

As per the docs from the section on [updating multiple objects at once:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

> **You can only set non-relation fields and [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) fields using this
>   method.** To update a non-relation field, provide the new value as a
>   constant. To update `ForeignKey` fields, set the new value to be the new
>   model instance you want to point to.

**Query-2:**

If you want to delete all the objects of m2m table, you can use [`.delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete) queryset method.

```
MyModel.objects.all().delete() # deletes all the objects
```

Another method is to execute the raw SQL directly. This method is faster than the previous one.

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name")
```

**Query-3:**

To get the table name of a model, you can use [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#db-table) model `Meta` option.

```
my_model_object._meta.db_table # gives the db table name
```

Comment: Yes, but I have no m2m MyModel class as you see, I have only today_ref_viewed_ips = ManyToManyField, has it also some meta information?

Comment: `UniqAddress` is the model of `today_ref_viewed_ips`. To get its table name, you can use `uniq_address_object._meta.db_table`. Using `.delete()` on this model will delete all the objects in the `UniqAddress` table. Think twice if you want to do `UniqAddress.objects.delete()` as all the objects of this model will be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to update the m2m fields only and do not want to delete the m2m objects you can use the following:

```
#if you have **list of pk** for new m2m objects

today_ref_pk = [1,2,3]
u = MyUser.objects.get(pk=1)
u.today_ref_viewed_ips.clear()
u.today_ref_viewed_ips.add(*today_ref_pk)
```

for django >=1.11 [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set):

```
# if you have the **list of objects** for new m2m and you dont have the 
# issue of race condition, you can do the following:

today_ref_objs = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
u = MyUser.objects.get(pk=1)
u.today_ref_viewed_ips.set(today_ref_objs, clear=True)
```