# Clear all data of certain fields for all objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to clear all the data of a certain field within a model for all of the objects.
Something like this:

```
#models.py
class A(models.Model):
    someProperty = models.ManyToManyField(SomeModel)
```

```
#views.py
object = A.objects.all()
object.someProperty.all().clear()
```

I understand this is probably simple but I have been looking through the django documentation and haven't been able to find a good way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: might be looking for the update queryset method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update

Comment: @AMG Since this is a `ManyToManyField`, I can't call that can I?

Comment: I got too excited. Missed the many to many. One moment.

Comment: does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553176/4872140 You don't have a through table specified so you'll need to use the _meta to get the table name

Comment: this one might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798313/4872140 Goes at it from the SomeModel side `some_model.a_set.clear()` although I don't think that will get exactly what you want.