# How to bulk-associate an object to multiple objects that have ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(
        Keyword, related_name="posts_that_have_this_keyword"
    )
```

Now I want to migrate all `Post`s of a *wrongly named* `Keyword` to a new *properly named* `Keyword`. And there are multiple *wrongly named* `Keyword`s.

I can do the following but it leads to a number of SQL queries.

```
for keyword in Keyword.objects.filter(is_wrongly_named=True).iterator():
    old = keyword
    new, _ = Keyword.objects.get_or_create(name='some proper name')
    for note in old.notes_that_have_this_keyword.all():
        note.keywords.add(old)
    old.delete()
```

Is there a way I can achieve this while minimizing the SQL queries executed?

I prefer Django ORM solution to a raw SQL one, because I jumped right into the Django ORM without studying deep into SQL, not so familiar with SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not just rename the Keywords?

Comment: @IainShelvington I can't, because there already exists Keyword with `'some proper name'`. Simply renaming them will cause `IntegrityError`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update manytomany field in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194737/how-to-update-manytomany-field-in-django)

Comment: @IainShelvington It looks like the code I posted in this question. Didn't help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform bulk operations with M2M relationships I suggest that you act directly on the table that joins the two objects. Django allows you to access this otherwise anonymous table by using the `through` attribute on the M2M attribute on an object.

So, to get the table that joins Keywords and Posts you could reference either `Keyword.posts_that_have_this_keyword.through` or `Post.keywords.through`. I'd suggest you assign a nicely named variable to this like:

```
KeywordPost = Post.keywords.through
```

Once you get a hold onto that table bulk operations can be performed.

bulk remove bad entries

```
KeywordPost.objects.filter(keyword__is_wrongly_named=True).delete()
```

bulk create new entries

```
invalid_keyword_posts = KeywordPost.objects.filter(keyword__is_wrongly_named=True)
post_ids_to_update = invalid_keyword_posts.values_list("post_id", flat=True)
new_keyword_posts = [KeywordPost(post_id=p_id, keyword=new_keyword) for p_id in post_ids_to_update]
KeywordPost.objects.bulk_create(new_keyword_posts)
```

Basically you get access to all the features that the ORM provides on this join table. You should be able to achieve much better performance that way.

You can read up more on the through attribute here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly I wanted. Now I got a better grasp of what `Through` model does. Thank you.

Comment: It's a super powerful concept to learn, hopefully you find it in handy in the future!