# how we can delete an element from ManyToMany realtion in django models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

i create a models in django , with ManyToMany relation , and i have a problem :

```
 class KeyCat(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class Keyword(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(KeyCat)
```

that create two table :  "keycat", "keyword" and "keyword_category"
i want to delete from "keywords_keyword_category" a row where id=1

Comment: So why you are not showing us keyword_category model?

Comment: I would also say that you are missing keyword field in keywords, and it is not clear what do you mean by keywords_keyword_category" a row where id=1.

Comment: If you want to remove a Category object related with a Keyword object you just need to call `remove`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update manytomany field in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194737/how-to-update-manytomany-field-in-django)